# No member named 'setMargin' in 'QwtPlotLayout' - Convert Qt4.7 to Qt5.8

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I need to **convert Qt legacy code from 4.7 to 5.8**, I have a compilation error in Qt Creator 4.2.1 Clang 7.0(Apple) 64bit. I'm using latest Qwt 6.1.3

**Looking in .cpp file**

```
#include "frmMainChart_UI.h"
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <qwt_plot_layout.h>
#include <qwt_legend.h>
#include "mpiDateScale.h"
#include "mpiPercentScale.h"

void frmMainChart_UI::setupUI(QWidget *parent_)
{
    frmMainTableViewTree_UI::setupUI(QMap<int, QString>(), false, parent_);
    delete frmMainTableViewTree_UI::tableCopy;
    delete frmMainTableViewTree_UI::table;

    chart = new mpiChart(widget);
    chart->setAxisScaleDraw(QwtPlot::xBottom, new mpiDateScale());
    chart->setAxisScaleDraw(QwtPlot::yLeft, new mpiPercentScale());
    chart->plotLayout()->setCanvasMargin(20);
    chart->plotLayout()->setMargin(20);  // BROKE convert Qt4 to Qt5
    chartZoomer = new mpiPlotZoomer(chart->canvas()); // BROKE convert Qt4 to Qt5
    chartLegend = new QwtLegend(chart);
    chart->insertLegend(chartLegend, QwtPlot::RightLegend);

    QLinearGradient grad(0, 0, 1, 1);
    grad.setCoordinateMode(QGradient::StretchToDeviceMode);
    grad.setColorAt(0, Qt::white);
    grad.setColorAt(1, QColor(220, 220, 220));
```

**2 Errors in .cpp**

../src/ui/frmMainChart_UI.cpp:18:26: **error: no member named 'setMargin' in 'QwtPlotLayout'**
    chart->plotLayout()->setMargin(20);  // BROKE convert Qt4 to Qt5

../src/ui/frmMainChart_UI.cpp:19:23: **error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'mpiPlotZoomer'**
    chartZoomer = new mpiPlotZoomer(chart->canvas()); // BROKE convert Qt4 to Qt5

```
           ^
```

**5 warnings and 2 errors generated**
make: *** [frmMainChart_UI.o] Error 1
06:58:25: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project mypersonalindex (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
06:58:25: Elapsed time: 00:01.

The **Qwt 6.1.3 Docs** has member function http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_layout.html

```
void    setCanvasMargin (int margin, int axis=-1)
```

But NO Member Function being used

```
setMargin
```

My C++ skill is pretty limited, do you see any minor tweaks that could convert this from Qt4 to Qt5. ... so what is the replacement?

Looking at mpiChart.h likely relates to canvas() error

```
#ifndef MPICHART_H
#define MPICHART_H

#include "qwt_plot.h"

class mpiChart : public QwtPlot
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    mpiChart(QWidget *parent_ = 0):
        QwtPlot(parent_)
    {}

public slots:
    void exportChart();
};

#endif // MPICHART_H
```

And Looking in mpiPlotZoomer.h relates to canvas() error

```
#ifndef MPIPLOTZOOMER_H
#define MPIPLOTZOOMER_H

#include <qwt_plot_zoomer.h>
#include <qwt_plot_canvas.h>  // JDL convert Qt4 to Qt5
#include <qwt_compat.h>  // JDL convert Qt4 to Qt5

class mpiPlotZoomer: public QwtPlotZoomer
{
public:
    mpiPlotZoomer(QwtPlotCanvas *canvas_):
        QwtPlotZoomer(canvas_, false)
    {
        setTrackerMode(AlwaysOn);
    }

    virtual QwtText trackerText(const QwtDoublePoint &pos_) const;
};

#endif // MPIPLOTZOOMER_H
```

Comment: What version of Qwt were you using with Qt 4.7?

Comment: Strange, Qwt with Qt 4.7 appears to be Qwt 5.5.5 from 2011, (  but latest Qwt has this 1.6.3  version that is now installed with Qt5.8 )

Comment: Latest qwt version is 6.1.3, not 1.6.3: http://qwt.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: `mpiChart.cpp` is useless, `mpiChart.h` would help.

Comment: `mpiPlotZoomer.cpp` is useless too, `mpiPlotZoomer.h` would help

Comment: By the way, have you checked my answer?

Comment: WOW used and it appears to be fine!, awesome!   chartZoomer = new mpiPlotZoomer(qobject_cast<QwtPlotCanvas*>(chart->canvas() ));  // JDL convert Qt4 to Qt5 jpo38

Comment: @jpo38.    Only third day on SO,  thanks for this awesome insight!   How does one indicate I used the second answer of two on the canvas() error ?

Comment: Commenting the answer would be just fine, but you probably need more reputation to be allowed to comment other posts than yours.

Comment: Thanks,   Is it possible  to connect with you in the future on Qwt topic, I'm now going to improve the UI now that it's all working in QT5 with Qwt6

Comment: Sure. When you need, post a new question. Then add a comment here to inform me, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `setMargin` function has been removed between Qwt version you were using for Qt 4.7 and Qwt 1.6.3 you are using with 5.8, you have no other choice than:

- Replace `setMargin` calls by `setCanvasMargin` if that fits your needs
- Or, remove `setMargin` calls

Try both, and see which one looks the best when displaying the GUI.

For the `canvas()` error, it's hard to tell without seeing `mpiChart` and `mpiPlotZoomer` declaration. However, I'll give it a try:

`canvas()` used to return a `QwtPlotCanvas*` in the past. For recent versions of Qwt it returns a `QWidget*`. So if your `mpiPlotZoomer` constructor expects a `QwtPlotCanvas*` as parameter, you'll have to:

- Replace `mpiPlotZoomer` parameters type from `QwtPlotCanvas*` by `QWidget*`. May work if the guy who wrote the `mpiPlotZoomer` class does not actually use and `QwtPlotCanvas` members/attributes (he may only use it for parenting purpose)
- Or replace `mpiPlotZoomer(chart->canvas());` by `mpiPlotZoomer( qobject_cast<QwtPlotCanvas*>( chart->canvas() ) );` which will hoepfully work fine.